# LEFT JOIN with multiple tables. Poor performance

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I need to optimize the below query. I have a lot of records in tables: a, b, c, d and the query time is very long. Please for help.

```
SELECT main.*, items.*
FROM main
LEFT JOIN (
  (SELECT a.*, 1 AS `type` FROM a) UNION
  (SELECT b.*, 2 AS `type` FROM b) UNION
  (SELECT c.*, 3 AS `type` FROM c) UNION
  (SELECT d.*, 4 AS `type` FROM d)
)
items ON main.`to` = items.id AND main.`type` = items.`type`
WHERE main.id > 0
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: A LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY is a bit unpredictable; but your best bet is UNIONing four JOIN queries, rather than JOINing to a UNION of four queries. ...assuming there are indexes for main.(`to`, `type`) and a|b|c|d.(`id`, `type`)

Comment: No explain results, no index information, no indication of record counts, nor run time. How do you expect us to help just based on a single query?

Comment: I don't think indexes on `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` will help, because he's joining with the result of the `UNION`, not the original tables.

Comment: Isn't this kind of problem symptomatic of poor design?

Comment: @Barmar I meant such indexes would help with the alternate version I suggested (of unioning joins rather than joining to a union).

Comment: Changing `UNION` (which defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`) to `UNION ALL` will help some.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, the query could deliver any 20!

Answer (score 0):

Yuck!  Something like this:

```
SELECT main.*, z.*
    FROM (
    ( SELECT  1 AS type, main.id AS mid, a.*, xx
        FROM  main
        JOIN  a  ON a.id = main.to
        WHERE  main.id > 0  AND main.type = 1
        ORDER BY  xx
        LIMIT  20 )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  2 AS type, main.id, b.*, xx
        FROM  main
        JOIN  b  ON a.id = main.to
        WHERE  main.id > 0  AND main.type = 2
        ORDER BY  xx
        LIMIT  20 )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  3 AS type, main.id, c.*, xx
        FROM  main
        JOIN  c  ON a.id = main.to
        WHERE  main.id > 0  AND main.type = 3
        ORDER BY  xx
        LIMIT  20 )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  4 AS type, main.id, d.*, xx
        FROM  main
        JOIN  d  ON a.id = main.to
        WHERE  main.id > 0  AND main.type = 4
        ORDER BY  xx
        LIMIT  20 )
      ORDER BY xx
      LIMIT 20 ) z
    JOIN main  ON main.id = z.mid
ORDER BY xx;
```

Plus indexes:

```
main: PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX(type, xx, id, to)
a,b,c,d:  PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Notes:

- I assume you really want to sort by `xx`, which is in `main`.
- I assume all tables have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`
- The 4-col index on `main` is somewhat helpful at doing the filtering and order by; it is "covering".
- The 6 `ORDER BY + LIMIT` will minimize the intermediate table to 80 rows.  The last one is because the subquery need not preserve the ordering.
- `main.id > 0` is a pain -- can we get rid of it?
- `ALL` instead of `DISTINCT` on the assumption that there will be no dups.
- `SELECT *` is a pain; can it be avoided?  I have messed up the exact list of columns because of it.
- The `JOIN` back to `main` is to avoid hauling around all of `main.*`; instead only 80 will need to be fetched.

Comment: Looks nice but I think that this type of solution doesn't allow to create pagination.